# Adding a formatted date on to the end of a concat function

Tags: excel, vba, date, format, concatenation

I'm currently looking to add an updating date in a DD/MM format to the end of a string of text currently generated by an existing macro.

```
Sub Nomediatidy()

 Dim w1 As Worksheet
 Dim w2 As Worksheet
    Dim result As Range
    Dim FirstRow As Integer


    Set w1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set w2 = Worksheets("Master List")

    FirstRow = 0

    With w1.Range("F:F")
        Set result = .Find(What:="No Media", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)

        If Not result Is Nothing Then
            FirstRow = result.Row
            Do
                w1.Range("H" & result.Row) = w1.Range("F" & result.Row) + " Available - PAM/Edit to Advise " & w1.Range("H" & result.Row)
                Set result = .FindNext(result)
            Loop While Not result Is Nothing And result.Row <> FirstRow
        End If
    End With

    Set w1 = Nothing
    Set result = Nothing


Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

On the line where it says "Available - PAM/Edit to Advise" I want to add todays date. However I can't for the life of me work out how to get it in there without the debugger kicking up some kind of error. I'm probably just over thinking it, but any advice would be appreciated

Comment: _I can't for the life of me work out how to get it in there without the debugger kicking up some kind of error_. In programming, "without the debugger kicking up some kind of error" translates with "I get a run-time error on this line saying this, another run-time error on this other line saying that, etc.". Would you please add this part for us to help?

Comment: Add `& Format$(Now, "dd/mm")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change
`w1.Range("H" & result.Row) = w1.Range("F" & result.Row) + " Available - PAM/Edit to Advise " & w1.Range("H" & result.Row)`

to `w1.Range("H" & result.Row) = w1.Range("F" & result.Row) & " Available - PAM/Edit to Advise " & w1.Range("H" & result.Row) & " " & format(now, "DD/MM")`

This will add a space at the end of what you have so far and then follow it by the current date from the now function, which takes the date and time from the system clock. And then formats it to be only "DD/MM"